# Sub-domain Stores on Local Dev Server

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, .htaccess, apache2

I have a live Magento site with a main store and also white-label stores located on sub-domains, all running out of the same Magento website. I'm using .htaccess to direct sub-domains to the corresponding stores like so:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.whitelabel.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=whitelabel
SetEnvIf Host www\.whitelabel.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^whitelabel.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=whitelabel
SetEnvIf Host ^whitelabel.mysite\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

This works great on my live site. However, I copied everything to a local Apache dev instance on an Ubuntu VM, and the sub-domains don't load their corresponding stores; they all just load the main store. I didn't make any changes to the .htaccess file. My virtual host file seems to be correct:

```
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
ServerAlias whitelabel.mysite.com
ServerAlias www.whitelabel.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html
```

I think my hosts file is correct:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.com
127.0.0.1       www.mysite.com
127.0.0.1       whitelabel.mysite.com
127.0.0.1       www.whitelabel.mysite.com
```

If I go to mysite.com in a browser on my dev box, it loads my main store, as it should. But if I go to whitelabel.mysite.com, it also loads my main store, but it should load my white-label store. What am I missing?

Comment: It's not a proper solution but it's one of the solution just rename your local.xml and install again

Comment: Most likely `SetEnvIf` isn't working as expected, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212292/setenvif-http-host-not-working

Comment: Thank you, Boomer. It's not SetEnvIf. I tried simply MAGE_RUN_CODE=whitelabel MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store and it still does not work. In index.php, isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) is false.